# Falling from a high cliff

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, collision, free-fall

I've always wondered about the reason why falling from a high cliff could actually cause death, is it the normal force exerted back from the ground? or is it related to energy? or what? thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the kinetic energy you acquire while falling is dissipated within your body (by bone breakage, etc.) over the duration of your collision with the ground. Because that duration is so short, the power developed is correspondingly large, and if the height from which you fell is sufficient, you will die of the resulting damage.

Comment: Thank you , but, how can we relate this to forces?

Comment: you start with the idea that the earth must apply a force to your body of sufficient magnitude so as to (as a first approximation) reverse its momentum vector within a certain amount of time defined as the time between first contact and the time at which your downward velocity is zero. Since this time is hard to estimate, you return to the energy dissipation argument instead and hope you never fall from a cliff.

Comment: I hope so, thnx though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to think about it in terms of force, this is how I used to think of impact forces. If you're thinking in terms of F = ma, then the acceleration has to be extremely high in order to bring this abject to a stop in a very short distance and period of time (practically instantaneously) resulting in a very high impact force. Same thing if we think of the classical definition of force, change in momentum with respect to time (**F = dP/dt =  m(dV/dt) <=> F = ma** ,assuming mass remains constant), large change in momentum in a very short period of time results in high impact force.